# Google Sheet Query Formula Issue

Tags: google-sheets

Using below Query formula it is working perfectly but there is 1 issue in it, that if first Column is empty such as "AB" it will not work (Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC) that error is occur.

I have multiple sheets where mostly multiple columns are empty i mean If AB is empty then AC has values then AD is empty and so on.

please help in this regard.

=QUERY(A3:AZ27,"Select A, SUM(AB), SUM(AC), SUM(AD), SUM(AE), SUM(AF), SUM(AG), SUM(AH) Where A is not null Group by A LABEL A 'SuitA', SUM(AB) 'Jan', SUM(AC) 'FEB', SUM(AD) 'MAR', SUM(AE) 'APR', SUM(AF) 'MAY', SUM(AG) 'JUN', SUM(AH) 'JUL' ",1)

Comment: through `SUM(AB), SUM(AC), SUM(AD),.. SUM(AH)` in these cells `AB3:AH27` let try put more an entry like add 2 new more lines with 0 in these `AB26:AH27` cells if you don't understand you can ask me more

Comment: @zummontt Yeah if i add 0 then it works. But the issue is i cannot add 0 or else in these cells because bringing the data using query thrice time to put above formula to get the desired result. If i used thise simple formula that is first =Unique(A:A) then =SUMIF($A$3:$A$27,$BB15,AO$3:AO$27) it works fine. But need to do this via above formula.

Comment: Oh! I see I think have an idea, but let me try first. Your formula `QUERY` might change a lot

Comment: I HAVE LOOKING FOR A SOLUTION AND TRYING TO FIX IT SINCE MORNING. The issue is if any column will be empty in above SUM(Columns) then it will not work and give error

Comment: @ zummontt i would really appreciate if could.

Comment: Yes! figured out you can see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `=QUERY()` doesn't have enough data to read

Your code I tried using is technically correct, but you need to fill more data

so use `QUERY` with `ARRAY` will work

```
=QUERY({A3:AA27,ARRAYFORMULA(AB3:AH27+0),AI3:AZ27}, "
  Select Col1, SUM(Col28), SUM(Col29), SUM(Col30), SUM(Col31), SUM(Col32), SUM(Col33), SUM(Col34) 
  Where Col1 is not null 
  Group by Col1 
  LABEL Col1 'SuitA', SUM(Col28) 'Jan', SUM(Col29) 'FEB', SUM(Col30) 'MAR', SUM(Col31) 'APR', SUM(Col32) 'MAY', SUM(Col33) 'JUN', SUM(Col34) 'JUL'
", 1)
```

add `{`range`}` to change `range reference` to `array`

then QUERY needs to change from `"SELECT A, AB,..."` to `"SELECT Col1, Col28,..."`
if you provide continuously as `query({A3:AA27},...)` But if you provide just `query({B3:AA27},...)` then `column B = Col1` and go on until last `column AA = Col27`

`ARRAYFORMULA(`range`+0)` to force empty cells to be filled with zero

[image: QUERY FOR TOO SMALL DATA]

Comment: I'm glad it helps